# Add class to current tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm dynamically populating a table. If a certain condition applies, I want to add a class to the current `tr`:

```
number = 3;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var row = "";
  row += "<tr><td>Test" + i + "</td></tr>"

  $('#mytable').find('tbody:last').append(row);

  if (i == number) {
    $('#mytable').find('tbody:last').addClass("red");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the class is being added to all `tr`s, not only the one of them.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lan0fv36/).

Comment: `"tbody:last"` finds the last `<tbody>` element, not the last `<tr>`.

Comment: $('#mytable').find('tbody tr:last').addClass("red");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
number = 3;    
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr>');
  if (i == number) row.addClass('red');
  row.append($('<td>').html('Test'+i));
  $('#mytable').find('tbody:last').append(row);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').eq(number).addClass('red');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lan0fv36/1/)

Note that the index provided to `eq()` is zero-based. Thus passing 3 will select the fourth element.

---

The counter in the loop `i` can also be used with conditional operator

```
row += "<tr" + (i === number ? ' class="red"' : '') + "><td>Test" + i + "</td></tr>"
//              ^^ ================================ ^^
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lan0fv36/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Create the row as a jQuery object so you have a reference to it. Then you can simply add a class to it if your clause is met rather than having to find it again.

EG:

```js
var number = 3;
var $tbody = $('#mytable');
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
    var $row = $("<tr><td>Test"+i+"</td></tr>");// create the row as a jquery object so we have a reference to it    
    $tbody.append($row);// append it to the table   
    if (i == number) {// if your clause is met
        $row.addClass("red");// add a classname
    }
}
```

```css
.red {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mytable tbody:last tr:last').addClass("red");
```

This will select last tr and adds class only to last tr(which you just appended)

Answer (score 0):

No need to modify more on this just replace one thing **find('tbody tr:last')**, please find code below

```
number = 3;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 var row = "";
 row += "<tr><td>Test" + i + "</td></tr>"

 $('#mytable').find('tbody:last').append(row);

 if (i == number) {
   $('#mytable').find('tbody tr:last').addClass("red");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `addClass()` altogether by adding a class directly when constructing the HTML:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var row = "";
  var rowClass = (i == number) ? " class='red' " : "";
  row += "<tr"+rowClass+"><td>Test" + i + "</td></tr>"

  $('#mytable').find('tbody:last').append(row);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k9fazum/

Otherwise as Pointy has pointed out you should select `tr` not `tbody` and Tushar's answer demonstrates how you can select specific `tr` via indices when `:latest` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:  $('#mytable').find('**tbody:last**').addClass("red");
 Solution :  $('#mytable').find('**tbody tr:last**').addClass("red");

```
 number = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var row = "";
      row += "<tr><td>Test" + i + "</td></tr>"

      $('#mytable').find('tbody:last').append(row);

      if (i == number) {  
        $('#mytable').find('tbody tr:last').addClass("red");
      }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shadiq_aust/Lan0fv36/4/